ODE y'=f(x)y: When y=0 only at some points
To solve for $y(x)$ in $y'=f(x)y$.
I was taught to consider case where $y=0$ and $y\neq0$.
For $y \neq 0$, can get $\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int{f(x) dx}$, then $y(x)=C e^{\int{f(x) dx}}$, where $C \neq 0$.
For $y=0$, $y(x)=0$ everywhere.
But, then I also heard someone mentioning $y=0$ and $y \neq 0$ means $y$ is 0 everywhere, and $y$ is not 0 everywhere. Thus, missing the case where $y$ is 0 somewhere and not somewhere.
My first thought is to break it into intervals with endpoints where $y$ is 0, then adding those intergals. But $\int \frac{dy}{y}$ may not exists, when $y \to 0$. Like the area under $\frac{1}{x}$ graph around 0.
The course material didn`t go into details, so I was wondering there are some theorm behind. Any reference to them would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.
edit:
remove typo 'with k is a constant'

since the ode is linear, then $y=0$ is not singular solution. It can be obtained from general solution when $c_1=0$. So there is no point of saying $y=0$ is also a solution.

"with $k$ is a constant" What $k$?

If you solve it using an integrating factor instead of separation of variables, you don't need to split into cases, and the question never even arises.

@HansLundmark I'll take a look on that

Assuming $f$ is continuous, this differential equation satisfies the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem, so two solutions that are equal at one point will always be equal.  In particular, the constant $y = 0$ is a solution, so no other solution can ever be $0$.
